# Python modules vs packages

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

I was reading a document and I encountered the part below:

> A ​module​ is nothing more, nothingless than a directory with ​__init__.py​ file inside. It should contain other Python files with the logic related to the module's purpose.

Is this definition correct?

(As I know, a Python module is  a file, whose extension is py, which contains Python code. And as I remember a directory which contains dunder init(`__init__.py`) file is called as Python package.)

Comment: A package is also a module, in that I can import it by name.  I would call the definition just a bit sloppy, since it doesn't allow for single-file modules.

Comment: [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-module) may help

Comment: Both definitions are bad. Modules don't need to be .py files (they can be .so for example), and packages don't need to be directories on disk (they can be zipfiles for example). Modules and packages may be dynamically created in memory and may not exist on a filesystem at all. And namespace packages are a type of Python package which does not have any `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is incorrect.

While a "package" is also a "module", a single ".py" file comprises, in itself,
a module, with no need to be a directory, or have an `__init__` file inside it.

A package, on the other hand, yes, is usually  (and defined as) a directory with an `__init__.py` and optionally other files.

(However packages can be presented in other formats such as .egg or zip files, or even custom formats with corresponding customized importing mechanisms, which are plugable)